# Connect to a container running in Docker (Redis) from Cloud Run Emulator locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-code, google-cloud-intellij

I'm making local cloud run services with the Cloud Code plugin to Intellij (PyCharm) but the locally deployed service cannot connect to the redis instance running in Docker:

```
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.
```

I can connect to the locally running redis instance from a python shell, it's just the cloud run service running in minikube/docker that cannot seem to connect to it.

Any ideas?

Edit since people are suggesting completely unrelated posts - The locally running Cloud Run instance makes use of Docker and Minikube to run, and is automatically configured by Cloud Code for Intellij. I suspect that Cloud Code for intellij puts Cloud Run instances into an environment that cannot access services running on MacOS localhost (but can access the Internet), which is why I tagged those specific items in the post.  Please limit suggestions to ones that takes these items into account.

Comment: Please show information on how you're connecting to your Redis instance. Also, what's 
 on your Dockerfile and your dependencies? There's a very similar thread to your post and this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088409/error-111-connecting-to-localhost6379-connection-refused-django-heroku

Comment: Thanks but that's not similar at all.  The locally running cloud run instance makes use of docker and minikube to run, and is automatically configured by Cloud Code for Intellij.  I suspect that Cloud Code for intellij puts Cloud Run instances into an environment that cannot access services running on MacOS localhost, which is why I tagged those specific items in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check Docker network using:

```
docker network list
```

You'll see a network called  `cloud-run-dev-internal`. You need to connect your Redis container to that network. To do that, run this command (This instruction assumes that your container name is **some-redis**):

```
docker network connect cloud-run-dev-internal some-redis
```

Double check that your container is connected to the network:

```
docker network inspect cloud-run-dev-internal
```

Then connect to Redis Host using the container name:

```
import redis
...

redis_host = os.environ.get('REDISHOST', 'some-redis')
redis_port = int(os.environ.get('REDISPORT', 6379))
redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host, port=redis_port)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed.  The docker network inspect command was especially useful since the bridge uses local network address space (not 127.0.0.1).